# Xslt : Create root element (Starting Tag )dynamically

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xmlspy

Following are the nodes in XML Data

```
 <WebServiceUrl>"http://webser.part.site"</WebServiceUrl>
<UserName>nida</UserName>
<Passsword>123</Password>
</ProcessData>
```

I have passed this node value to Xslt Service now i have this url NODE value in parameter e-g

```
<xsl:param name="UserName"/>
<xsl:param name="Password"/>
<xsl:param name="WebServiceUrl"/>
```

Now i want to create a soapenv:Envelope tag and use this value in it

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="$WebServiceUrl">
```

So the final outPut which i want from XSLT Code is as :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"          xmlns:web="http://webservice2.partner.insite">
 <soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<web:upload>
<web:username>nida</web:username>
<web:password>123</web:password>
</web:upload></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Please help me out**

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
     xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     exclude-result-prefixes="ext soapenv">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:param name="pUserName" select="'nida'"/>
      <xsl:param name="pPassword" select="'123'"/>
      <xsl:param name="pWebServiceUrl" select="'http://webser.part.site'"/>

        <xsl:variable name="vrtfDummy">
         <xsl:element name="web:dummy" namespace="{$pWebServiceUrl}"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="vNS" select="ext:node-set($vrtfDummy)/*/namespace::web"/>

     <xsl:template match="/*">
       <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
           <xsl:copy-of select="$vNS"/>
         <soapenv:Body>
           <xsl:element name="web:upload" namespace="{$vNS}">
             <xsl:element name="web:username" namespace="{$vNS}">
               <xsl:value-of select="$pUserName"/>
             </xsl:element>
             <xsl:element name="web:password" namespace="{$vNS}">
               <xsl:value-of select="$pPassword"/>
             </xsl:element>
           </xsl:element>
         </soapenv:Body>
         </soapenv:Envelope>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (not used), produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webser.part.site">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:upload>
         <web:username>nida</web:username>
         <web:password>123</web:password>
      </web:upload>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: please see this ,i am facing the error in the specified node described below

Comment: When i apply this XSLT to the Given XML I get the Following Output which is not correct.


    <soapenv:Envelope      xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
    <web:upload xmlns:web="http://webser.part.site"> 
    <web:username>nida</web:username>
   <web:password>123</web:password>
   </web:upload>
   </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Please have a look into the above code , its not giving the required Output.

Comment: @NidaSulheri: So, what isn't as expected in the output?