# Xslt : Creating root element dynamically by parameters

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces

Following are the nodes in XML Data

```
<ProcessData
 <WebServiceUrl>"http://webser.part.site"</WebServiceUrl>
<UserName>nida</UserName>
<Passsword>123</Password>
</ProcessData>
```

I have passed this node value to Xslt Service now i have this url NODE value in parameter e-g

```
<xsl:param name="UserName"/>
<xsl:param name="Password"/>
<xsl:param name="WebServiceUrl"/>
```

Now i want to create a soapenv:Envelope tag and use this value in it

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="$WebServiceUrl">
```

So the final outPut which i want from XSLT Code is as :

```
enter code here
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"          xmlns:web="http://webservice2.partner.insite">
 <soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<web:upload>
<web:username>nida</web:username>
<web:password>123</web:password>
</web:upload></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

When i apply this XSLT

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
     xmlns:soapenv="http:/`enter code here`/schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     exclude-result-prefixes="ext soapenv">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:param name="pUserName" select="'nida'"/>
      <xsl:param name="pPassword" select="'123'"/>
      <xsl:param name="pWebServiceUrl" select="'http://webser.part.site'"/>

        <xsl:variable name="vrtfDummy">
         <xsl:element name="web:dummy" namespace="{$pWebServiceUrl}"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="vNS" select="ext:node-set($vrtfDummy)/*/namespace::web"/>

     <xsl:template match="/*">
       <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
           <xsl:copy-of select="$vNS"/>
         <soapenv:Body>
           <xsl:element name="web:upload" namespace="{$vNS}">
             <xsl:element name="web:username" namespace="{$vNS}">
               <xsl:value-of select="$pUserName"/>
             </xsl:element>
             <xsl:element name="web:password" namespace="{$vNS}">
               <xsl:value-of select="$pPassword"/>
             </xsl:element>
           </xsl:element>
         </soapenv:Body>
         </soapenv:Envelope>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Please help me out** I am in real trouble as i am searching for the solution from a couple of days . i am new to XSLT so i dont know much about it . 
Please help me in acheiving the required output.

**When i apply Above XSLT code to the given XML i get Following OUTPUT Which is not correct.**

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soapenv:Body>
    <web:upload xmlns:web="http://webser.part.site">
   <web:username>nida</web:username>
    <web:password>123</web:password>
   </web:upload>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

**My desired OUTPUT is as Folllowing:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"          xmlns:web="http://webservice2.partner.insite">
 <soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<web:upload>
<web:username>nida</web:username>
<web:password>123</web:password>
 </web:upload></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xslt : Create root element (Starting Tag )dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808073/xslt-create-root-element-starting-tag-dynamically)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Please Help

Comment: Nida, Your identical question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808073/xslt-create-root-element-starting-tag-dynamically is completely answered -- what more "help" do you need? Please, dont ask the same question more than once.

Comment: Nida, Also, the shown output *isn't * what an XSLT 1.0 processor produces as output.

Answer (score 0):

Nida, AFAIK, XMLSPY doesn't have any `xxx:node-set()` extension.

**Try**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vNS" select="$vrtfDummy/*/namespace::web"/>
```

or, if this still leads to error, try using the MSXML or the Saxon namespace and `xxx:node-set()` function.